Nested tqdm loading bars not working in VSCode interactive window
Having two nested loading bars does not work for me in the interactive Python window in VSCode.
The following code
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    for j in tqdm(range(10), leave=False):
        sleep(0.1)

looks correctly in the terminal:

but only renders one bar in the interactive window

I have tried from tqdm.auto import tqdm, but that just gives me these empty bars

even after installing an old version of ipywidgets: pip3 install ipywidgets==7.7.2

This issue did exist in jupyter with interactive window, and switching jupyter versions didn't fix it, so I submitted the issue to github and wait for the developer to fix it.

@MingJie-MSFT nice, thank you for posting it there
